# "or" keyword doesn't work in search

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

I used to use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+or+sh+or+shell+or+awk+or+sed+or+jq+or+grep) to access questions that I'm interested in for almost a year, but now it doesn't work; it shows me a *404 Not Found* error. I got this link by searching for `[tag1] or [tag2] or ...` btw.

Why'd it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Huh, it works for me. ... Chrome / Win 10. I'm in western europe in case this is a local / country issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjxRC.png

Comment: Same: 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Opera / Win 10.

Comment: Maybe both you and @Scratte have an unlucky pick in the webfarm ...

Comment: I used the link in the Question directly. When I search "My watched tags" or pick "The following tags" the 404 doesn't happen. The difference is the wrapping of the or. `+or+` doesn't work. `%20or%20` does. So this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash%20or%20sh%20or%20shell%20or%20awk%20or%20sed%20or%20jq%20or%20grep) works.

Comment: When I access my favourite tags via the "Custom Filter" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?uqlId=917) in the sidebar, it works fine, but when I then *refresh*, I get a 404...

Comment: @Scratte yup, that works, thank you. But I didn't understand what had changed

Comment: thanks for reporting, you hit an issue with on our AspNetCore canary servers, this will be resolved shortly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've removed the affected server from rotation and a build will be going out shortly to address it. We've been testing a branch of our .NET Core port to find issues exactly like this so thanks for the heads up!